# Can anyone help me identify this font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, script

I am trying to find out what this font is. I have tried Whatthefont, whatfontis, mactherator and I Bold block results. No where close to the image. I am trying to determine the font for my wedding invitations.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This font is called [Melany Lane](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/yellow-design/melany-lane/regular/).

The extra filigree you see in your example on the "C" and "n" are [alternate glyphs](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/yellow-design/melany-lane/regular/glyphs.html) that are included in the font.

[image]

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: @user4386709 I had used it on some wedding invitations for a friend. I didn't have the font anymore and couldn't remember the name, but I only buy fonts from a few places so it was easy to find again.

Comment: I'm impressed!!!

Answer (score 0):

this is the closes i could find

http://www.dafont.com/forum/read/255679/sunshine-font

[image]